# Flyway migration with MySQL comments issue

Tags: mysql, gradle, yaml, flyway

First of all, I am not sure how I came to this state. I use mySQL5.7 and I recently upgraded few dependencies for my gradle project. After the upgrade it didn't like previous comments in my database migration files. By the way I didn't change database version. Some of the comments were made without a space like bellow and it was fine before. If I add spaces after '--' it works but it's an issue with other environments to which 
migration is already applied since migration files checksum is changed. Could anyone suggest me a solution? I initialize my local environment frequently and I need to make this work for all environments.

```
--My comments start here
```

Answer (score 1):

Your best option is to fix your scripts, so that they contain valid MySQL syntax and then run Flyway's repair command to realign the checksums.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Could you provide a link or steps that I can reference? I try to be cautious since I need to deal with production environment.

Comment: @user3123690 https://flywaydb.org/documentation/commandline/repair but I use the Maven plugin https://flywaydb.org/documentation/maven/repair I also use Spring. Flyway Maven plugin doesn't use Spring Boot settings so you must explicitly provide them. `mvn flyway:migrate -Dflyway.user=root -Dflyway.password= -Dflyway.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb -Dflyway.table=schema_version`.